Given $ r > 0 $ and the ODE $ y' + ry = R(t) $, find conditions on $ R(t) $ such that if $ y(t) $ is a solution then $ \lim_{t \to +\infty} y(t) = 0 $
Given $ r > 0 $ and the ODE $ y' + ry = R(t) $, find conditions on $ R(t) $ such that if $ y(t) $ is a solution then $ \lim_{t \to +\infty} y(t) = 0 $
It's a linear differential equation, and its solution will be given by the form $y(t)= \frac{\int e^{rt}R(t)}{e^{rt}} + \frac{c}{e^rt}$, if we solve the limit, we know that $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{c}{e^{rt}}=0$, so everything reduces to $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\int e^{rt}R(t)}{e^{rt}}=0$, here I don't know what else to do, I think I must bound, maybe using Cauchy-Schwarz.

Hint. Use the Laplace transform final value property.

You already found the condition: $R$ is such that
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\int_{t_0}^{t} e^{rs}R(s),ds}{e^{rt}}=0.
$$
